# vpn connection shortcut for different usersnames and passwords?

Tags: users, vpn, connection

can anyone tell me how to create a vpn connection in my desktop that requires both username and password each time ... cuz Im going to install ubuntu 10.04 on an old computer with more than 200 users... exactly sth like pbk on windows ...
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
nmcli con up id "NAME OF YOUR VPN"
```

[image]

[More informations](http://my30daysoflinux.blogspot.com/2011/11/create-desktop-shortcut-to-vpn.html)

[Check also How to Setup VPN](https://seed4.me/pages/setup/vpn-ubuntu)